# MomentJS only showing time on load

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

Using momentjs to get current times, however, I'm noticing its only getting the values during load. What is causing this here? My suspicion is `text()` is not proper for a dynamic value?

```
var zone = [
    est = 'America/New_York',
    cen = 'America/Mexico_City',
    mount = 'America/Denver',
    pac = 'America/Los_Angeles'
]
var est = moment.tz(moment(), zone[0]).format('HH:MM:ss a');
var cen = moment.tz(moment(), zone[1]).format('HH:MM:ss a');
var mount = moment.tz(moment(), zone[3]).format('HH:MM:ss a');
var pac = moment.tz(moment(), zone[4]).format('HH:MM:ss a');

$("#est").text(est)
$("#pac").text(pac)
$("#cen").text(cen)
$("#mount").text(mount)
```

Example of dom elements:

```
        <div class="clock">
            <p>Pacific</p>
            <p id="pac" class="time">1:00 PM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clock">
            <p>Mountain</p>
            <p id="mount" class="time">1:00 PM</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: shouldn't the function that sets the time be called with setInterval , so that it is called every minute or second , whatever be the unit you select?

Comment: I suppose it may be a misunderstanding on my part, then. I thought moment was meant to alleviate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moment()` gives you the current time *once*, and that's all. You need to update the time (for example, every second) yourself. Also, `$(...).text` updates the text content just once.

Try creating an [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval):

```
window.setInterval(() => {...code to execute...}, 1000);
```